# Disable "white fog" between routes on nativescript app

Tags: android, angular, routes, nativescript

I develop app only for Android OS and I have a problem with "white fog" between routes viewings (while page is loaded). I use Router for routing between pages. Could somebody help me how can I fix this? Here is a short sample video (if I tap to "go back" text, there is white fog while is page loading).

https://slack-files.com/T0L97VCSY-F32FW73H6-6288f56311

Routes are declared in @NgModule and defined like in NativeScript tutorial, like this:

```
export const routes = [
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full", terminal: true },
{ path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
{ path: "list", component: ListComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this issue here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/468

So it's bug in actual tns-core-modules version. I hope that in next update of this module will be fixed this.